# Use multiple databases and tables across an application in CakePHP

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, cakephp-2.0

For my job, I've build an web-based application with **CodeIgniter**. Now I want to rebuild this application in **CakePHP**, because I think it's a better framework which can do more and has more structure than my current framework.

I've started with the basic tutorial on the CakePHP website to create a small blog application. That works fine. I also combined this with Twitter Bootstrap.
Now I'm rebuilding my application.

**First I explain what my application does.** 
It displays a list (overview) of data from the database.
This database is located on localhost (MySQL) and is called "localdb1" (for this example).
The tabel is called "sheets".
This table contains data which I can use directly, but it also **contains id's that refer to other databases**.

For example a field that is called customer, which contains the customer's number. The customer's name is stored in another database (ODBC), located on another host ("remotehost2"). For this example the database is called "remotedb2" and the customernames are stored in the table "customers" in the field "customername".

For 2 days now, I'm struggling with the database system in CakePHP. As of the system uses name convention, it's not al clear for me.

**What have I done:**

- I've read and search the CakePHP documentation on there website, wich I think is very usefull, but I can't find the answer.
- I've shearch the internet (by Google offcourse) for an answer. I found many different possible solutions, but non are suitable or give several errors with the database connection.
- I've search in the QA of Stackoverflow. Same as above. :(

**How the result should look like:**

I want a list of records from localdb1.sheets, but I don't want to display the customer's number, but I want the customer's name, which i found in the remote database remotedb2.customers and can be found by the customer's number

**Can someone tell me how I should do that?**
The difficulty is, that I don't only want this, but I shall combine more databases and tables located on those 2 hosts. So I need a solution like a plugin (or if it's better a model) that is able to get content from the remotehost, or the localhost from other tables.

Comment: Here is the funny part: while people usually argue, which is the best framework, among the professional PHP developers the only agreed part is that the **two worst** frameworks for php are CodeIgniter and CakePHP.

Comment: @tereško - where have you seen this being discussed? I would have to disagree with your statement.

Comment: @Malachi , have you read the source of those frameworks? Have you researched MVC and MVC-inspired design patterns? Do you know what IoC, LoD, SOLID, SoC stand for? Lets put it this way ... I doubt that you disagreement was any weight in the discussion.

Comment: I started with CodeIgniter and then got a job with CakePHP. Then after a year I hated CakePHP and kept my side projects in CodeIgniter. Now I have one upcoming project that I am planning on migrating from CodeIgniter to Laravel.
Long story short, there is no "best" solution but rather the right tool for the job and I would not switch from CodeIgniter just because a framework is "better" but if you are missing functionality. Why refactor something unless it has technical debt or is broken?

Comment: Thanks for your opinions, but this is not a forum to discuss whether my choice is a good choice or not. I'm seeking for a solution to my problem. But so far, I didn't god an answer. Can someone please provide me with a decent piece of code?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know it will be useful to you or not but i am maintaining my multiple databases  of cloud with the use of below pattern.I hope it can work for you also...

In your database.php make a new connection object for second database

```
public $user = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'remotehost2',
    'login' => 'login_id',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'remotedb2',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

after that you can use that connction object using below syntax in your model

```
enter var $useDbConfig = 'table_name';
```

OR

you can maintain connections using below syntax also

```
 $options = array();
    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('table_name');
    $list = $db->rawQuery('select id, name from table_name;');
    while ($row = $db->fetchRow()) { 
        $options = Set::insert($options, $row["table_name"]["id"], $row["tablle_name"]["name"]);
    }
```

Comment: Though Cake uses Object, it is highly discouraged to use rawQuery, binding is a better option. Just worth a note ! :)